# Supplying stream as a source of data for a binary column when SqlBulkCopy is used

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, sqlbulkcopy, idatareader

If one needs to read data *from* SqlServer in a streamed fashion, there are some capabilities for that. Such as using `SqlDataReader` with `CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess`, and particularly when binary column data needs to be accessed there is the `GetStream(int)` method for that:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = connection;
cmd.CommandText = @"select 0x0123456789 as Data";

using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
{
    dr.Read();

    var stream = dr.GetStream(0);
    // access stream
}
```

But what about streaming data in the opposite direction, when one needs to feed data *to* SqlServer using `SqlBulkCopy`, and particularly if stream needs to be supplied as the source of data for a binary column?

I tried following

```
var cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
cmd2.Connection = connection;
cmd2.CommandText = @"create table #Test (ID int, Data varbinary(max))";
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

using (SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock, null))
{
    sbc.DestinationTableName = "#Test";
    sbc.EnableStreaming = true;

    sbc.ColumnMappings.Add(0, "ID");
    sbc.ColumnMappings.Add(1, "Data");

    sbc.WriteToServer(new TestDataReader());
}
```

Where `TestDataReader` implements `IDataReader` as follows:

```
class TestDataReader : IDataReader
{
    public int FieldCount { get { return 2; } }
    int rowCount = 1;
    public bool Read() { return (rowCount++) < 3; }
    public bool IsDBNull(int i) { return false; }

    public object GetValue(int i)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
            case 0: return rowCount;
            case 1: return new byte[] { 0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89 };
            default: throw new Exception();
        }
    }

    //the rest members of IDataReader
}
```

and it worked as expected.

However changing

```
case 1: return new byte[] { 0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89 };
```

to

```
case 1: return new MemoryStream(new byte[] { 0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89 });
```

caused exception `System.InvalidOperationException` with the message

> The given value of type MemoryStream from the data source cannot be
>   converted to type varbinary of the specified target column.

Is there a way to supply `Stream` from `IDataReader` (or probably `DbDataReader`) to `SqlBulkCopy` as the source of data for a binary column, without copying all its data into memory (byte array) first?

Comment: See webpage : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You are interested how to do that with custom IDataReader, or in reality you will use some existing data reader (like SqlDataReader)?

Comment: @Evk, with custom `IDataReader` or `DbDataReader` (I'm using custom implementation that feeds data from binary/xml files, however some dummy realization like in my question is sufficient).

Comment: I tried to inspect internals of `SqlBulkCopy` and `TdsParser` (on [ReferenceSource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com)). It seems that it should be possible. `SqlBulkCopy` calls `DbDataReader.GetStream(int)` method, then wraps result to `StreamDataFeed` which is passed then down to `TdsParser.WriteStreamFeed()` method. I tried to inherit my data reader from `DbDataReader`, but I was not able to make `GetStream(int)` called. Seems that I'm missing something.

Comment: While you were writing your comment I was writing an answer with exact this proposal :) however I did test it and it works for me fine (using the code from your sample).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure this is documented anywhere, but if do short inspection of `SqlBulkCopy` source code you may find out that it treats different data readers in different ways.
First, `SqlBulkCopy` does support streaming and `GetStream`, but you might notice that `IDataReader` interface does not contain `GetStream` method. So when you feed custom `IDataReader` implementation to `SqlBulkCopy` - it will not treat binary columns as streamed and will not accept values of `Stream` type.

On the other hand - `DbDataReader` *does* have this method. If you feed `SqlBulkCopy` an instance of `DbDataReader`-inherited class - it will treat all binary columns in streamed manner and it will call `DbDataReader.GetStream`.

So to fix your problem - inherit from `DbDataReader` like this:

```
class TestDataReader : DbDataReader
{
    public override bool IsDBNull(int ordinal) {
        return false;
    }

    public override int FieldCount { get; } = 2;
    int rowCount = 1;

    public override bool HasRows { get; } = true;
    public override bool IsClosed { get; } = false;

    public override bool Read()
    {
        return (rowCount++) < 3;
    }

    public override object GetValue(int ordinal) {
        switch (ordinal) {
            // do not return anything for binary column here - it will not be called
            case 0:
                return rowCount;
            default:
                throw new Exception();
        }
    }

    public override Stream GetStream(int ordinal) {
        // instead - return your stream here
        if (ordinal == 1)
            return new MemoryStream(new byte[] {0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89});
        throw new Exception();
    }
    // bunch of irrelevant stuff

}
```

Comment: Ok, I found why `GetStream` didn't get called in my second try of reader implementation (the one inherited from `DbDataReader` and not from `IDataReader`). Probably while playing with code in various directions, I introduced a mistake (I changed target column to `varbinary(100)` instead of `varbinary(max)` at some point). Your code combined with the code from question has worked fine. Great, that it's possible! Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

See following code

```
static int SendOrders(int totalToSend)
    {
      using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
      {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlTransaction tran = con.BeginTransaction())
        {
          var newOrders =
                  from i in Enumerable.Range(0, totalToSend)
                  select new Order
                  {
                    customer_name = "Customer " + i % 100,
                    quantity = i % 9,
                    order_id = i,
                    order_entry_date = DateTime.Now
                  };

          SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(con,
            SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints |
            SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers |
            SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls, tran);

          bc.BatchSize = 1000;
          bc.DestinationTableName = "order_queue";
          bc.WriteToServer(newOrders.AsDataReader()); 

          tran.Commit();
        }
        con.Close();

      }

      return totalToSend;

    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't seem helpful. I already have sample of `SqlBulkCopy` usage in my question. The question is about details of this usage. Particularly, is it possible to feed `Stream` data to binary column via `IDataReader` + `SqlBulkCopy` without copying all stream data into memory first.