# SQL Server Filetables/FileStream: Insert more than 2GB via Transact SQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server, filestream, sqlclient, filetable

I want to copy a file to an SQL Server Filetable using T-SQL. I cannot use the Win32 API (or `SqlFileStream` class for that matter) because the server does not expose SMB. The following code works very well for smaller files (up to 1GB):

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
using (Stream file = File.OpenRead(@"c:\Path\To\Large\file.bin"))
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 3600;
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE file_table SET file_stream = @stream WHERE path_locator = GetPathLocator(@path)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@path", @"\\HOST\INSTANCE\DB\file_table\largetest.bin");
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@stream", System.Data.SqlDbType.Binary, -1).Value = file;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The performance is decent (about 100MB/s), and passing the stream also works well and is easy on the client's memory. However, I see that the server's memory usage spikes during this query - apparently, SQL Server copies the entire stream into memory before writing it to disk. I also see disk IO to the tempdb. The query succeeds sometimes, but fails other times for the same file. Errors start occuring around 1.5GB filesize I've never been successful for a 4GB file. If the query fails, I get the following exception:
`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Internal error: An expression services limit has been reached. Please look for potentially complex expressions in your query, and try to simplify them.'`

Is there a better way to put a large file into a filetable?

Comment: Are you loading a 2GB blob in to a database? If so, _**why?**_

Comment: @gvee SQL Filetables is actually meant for storing large files. It doesn't actually store them in the database, it stores them on the file system and provides a T-SQL interface for it. The reason is that my application needs a location to store files for all clients as well as a Database, and I only want to expose a single server interface for both.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use [BCP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-and-export-bulk-data-by-using-the-bcp-utility-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) for this process. Then call stored procedure to update from temporary table.

```
cmd.CommandText= "exec xp_cmdShell 'bcp.exe'"+Database + ".." + TableName + " in "  + 
                 c:\Path\To\Large\file.bin + " -c -q -U " + UserId + " -P " + Password +  "-t  ";
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `SqlBulkCopy` for this. I don't have a copy & pasteable working example, Therefore I'll describe the steps to get there.

The idea is [stolen from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37318913/1055421) and adapted to FileTables. It's a very good idea to stream the data since we're handling large files. FileTables requires a minimum of two columns when inserting new data, which are `name` and `file_stream`. However, this would place the new file in the root of the FileTable. Therefore, we need to specify the `path_locator` field as well, which is of Type `HierarchyId`. So, the minimum working DbDataReader should have three columns: `name` (of type `String`), `file_path` (of Type `SqlHierarchyId`) and `file_stream` (of type `Stream`). You obviously have the `name` and the linked answer shows how to get the contents for `file_stream`, which leaves the `path_locator`

The missing link is generating a FileTable `HierarchyId` in code (there are examples how to create them in SQL, but this would be cumbersome):

```
public string GetNewHierarchyId()
{
    var g = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray();
    var used = 0;
    var strings = new List<string>();
    foreach (var i in new[] { 6, 6, 4 })
    {
        byte[] buf = new byte[8];
        Array.Copy(g, used, buf, (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? 0 : 2), i);
        used += i;
        strings.Add(BitConverter.ToUInt64(buf, 0).ToString());
    }
    return string.Join(".", strings) + "/";
}
```

To get the new `path_locator`, prepend the new file's parent directory's `path_locator`, which you can get via `SELECT GetPathLocator(@parentDir) FROM filetable`

Next, you need the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` Nuget package, because SqlBulkCopy needs to pass an argument of Type `SqlHierarchyId`, which you can then create like this: `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlHierarchyId.Parse(parentPathLocator & GetNewHierarchyId())`

I had to modify my bindingRedirects in the app.config for the `Microsoft.Sql.Types` package to work properly, by adding this:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
        <!-- <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" /> -->
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Naturally, you can add additional columns to `SqlBulkCopy` if you want to specify the file's attributes.